# PHP call class Closure with bound `$this` for decoration of dependent methods

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, closures, decorator

More and more often than before I meet vendor code which is hard to extend. Even if there's interface for every necessary class, it doesn't help a lot. The worst case which I see is when one public method uses another public method rather than dedicated class.

As a simple example let's imagine online shop application and `Order` entity. Typically Doctrine is used as ORM and we would have a repository class. Interface for it is shown below:

```php
interface ProductRepository 
{
    public function findReferenceBySku(string $sku): Product;

    public function findIdBySku(string $sku): int;
}
```

Method `findIdBySku` will make one query into database in order to find corresponding id of product by it's sku. while method `findReferenceBySku` will return either existing object stored in identity map of unit-of-work or generate proxy class. Proxy is necessary because for our specific use case we don't want load all product attributes (around hundred), but `Product` entity is necessary in order to use it as related entity (for `Price` for instance).

For now, let the `Product` look like this:

```php
class Product
{
    public function __construct(
        public int $id,
    ) { }
}
```

Repository implementation using database evidently will be such that `findReferenceBySku` uses `findIdBySku`.

```php
class ProductDatabaseRepository implements ProductRepository
{
    public function findReferenceBySku(string $sku): Product
    {
        $id = $this->findIdBySku($sku);

        return $this->getProductReference($id);
    }

    private function getProductReference(int $id)
    {
        // check entity manager for existing object
        // and generate proxy if not found

        return new Product($id);
    }
    
    public function findIdBySku(string $sku): int
    {
        $this->queryDatabase();

        return match($sku) {
            'sku1' => 1,
        };
    }
    
    protected function queryDatabase()
    {
        // note this method is not public

        var_dump('query database');
    }
}
```

During prices load it turned out to be that source has duplicated product skus and every time database query is made to correlate sku with id again and again.

To sort out such issue we'd decorate original repository and add caching logic to decorator.

```php
$repository = (new ProductCachedRepository(new ProductDatabaseRepository()));

var_dump('call1', $repository->findReferenceBySku('sku1'));
var_dump('call2', $repository->findReferenceBySku('sku1')); // cache hit
var_dump('call2', $repository->findReferenceBySku('sku1')); // cache hit
```

The final step would be to implement decorator class - that's where all issues show up! We can't stick to obvious implementation of `ProductCachedRepository::findReferenceBySku()` which would be to pass call to inner repository. Decorated object won't use our extended `findIdBySku()` method which gives us zero profit for a lot of effort.

```php
class ProductCachedRepository implements ProductRepository
{
    private array $cachedIds = [];
    
    public function __construct(
        private ProductRepository $inner
    ) {}
    
    public function findReferenceBySku(string $sku): Product
    {   
        // not able to delegate this logic directly to inner class
        // (loss of findIdBySku() overridden logic)
        // return $this->inner->findReferenceBySku($sku);
        
        // as well not able call decorated method with substitude this
        // return $this->inner->findReferenceBySku(...)->call($this, $sku);
        
        // therefore copy-paste like this
        // $id = $this->findIdBySku($sku);
        // return $this->getProductReference($id);
        
        // the only missing thing is the way to create closure from method,
        // forget bounded $this and call it with new one
        // just like creation of closure identical to method
        // with only difference - it is allowed to bind anywhere
        // return (function (string $sku): Product {
        //  $id = $this->findIdBySku($sku);
        // 
        //  return $this->getProductReference($id);    
        //})->call($this, $sku);
    }

    public function findIdBySku(string $sku): int
    {
        var_dump('check cache');

        return $this->cachedIds[$sku] 
                ??= $this->inner->findIdBySku($sku);
    }
    
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        // all not public methods of inner repository
        // which are not declared in current class
        // are delegated to inner repository

        return (fn() => $this->$name(...$arguments))
                ->call($this->inner);
    }
}
```

Is there any way of creation closure identical to method. I firstly thought of `return $this->inner->findReferenceBySku(...)->call($this, $sku);`, however it fails with warning and doesn't call method with new `$this`.

`Warning: Cannot bind method ProductDatabaseRepository::findReferenceBySku() to object of class ProductCachedRepository`.

Do you have any thoughts on this matter? How would you work around this issue?

Comment: Consider writing a simple but complete example and pushing it to a public github repository.  I can't quite follow where the problem is coming in based on your description.  But running something and seeing the actual error might help.

Comment: Problem here is on this line `$this->inner->findReferenceBySku(...)->call($this, $sku);` - php can't bind method closure to other instance. All the code above is the least possible complete example of problem. But yes, I'd publish it to repository.

Comment: You can play around with it here https://3v4l.org/CFE1u